# Dependency Injection and passing arguments

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I have a question about Dependency Injection in PHP.

I currently have this 3 classes:

Staff.php

```
<?php
class Staff
{
    public function name($id)
    {
        return 'returning staff with id ' . $id;
    }
}
```

Projects.php

```
<?php
class Projects
{
..... projects related functions
}
```

ProjectsManager.php

```
<?php

class ProjectsManager
{
    private $staff = null;
    private $projects = null;

    public function __construct(Staff $staff, Projects $projects)
    {
        $this->staff = $staff;
        $this->projects = $projects;
    }

    public function staff()
    {
        return $this->staff;
    }

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->projects;
    }
}
```

Those classes are instantiated like this:

```
    $staff    = new Staff;
    $projects = new Projects;
    $app      = new ProjectsManager($staff, $projects);

    echo $app->staff()->name(5);
```

The above is working, but what I would like to do is something like this:

```
$employee = $app->staff(5);
echo $employee->name();
echo $employee->position();
echo $employee->email();
```

How can I handle the dependency to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the set function in Staff class and call it in ProjectsManager:

```
<?php

class Staff 
{
    private $id = null;

    public function name()
    {
        return 'returning staff with id ' . $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}


class Projects
{
//..... projects related functions
}

class ProjectsManager
{
    private $staff = null;
    private $projects = null;

    public function __construct(Staff $staff, Projects $projects)
    {
        $this->staff = $staff;
        $this->projects = $projects;
    }

    public function staff($id = null)
    {
        $this->staff->setId($id);
        return $this->staff;
    }

    public function projects($val = null)
    {
        return $this->projects;
    }
}


$staff    = new Staff;
$projects = new Projects;
$app      = new ProjectsManager($staff, $projects);

$employee = $app->staff(5);
echo $employee->name();
```

Comment: That's spot on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$employee = $app->staff()->name(5);
//$app is the ProjectsManager
//$app->staff() returns it's Staff object
//staff()->name(5) Invokes the Staff object's name function
//Returns 'Returning staff with id 5'    

echo $employee->name();
echo $employee->position();
echo $employee->email();
```

To avoid confusion, I would also suggest prefix some of those functions with `get` (eg. `$app->getStaff()->getFromId(#)`)

Also, be sure to modify `staff()->name(#)` to *actually* return an object and not a string.

Comment: all goes well when I do $app->getStaff()->getId($id), but if I want to do: $app->getStaff()->getId($id)->name(), it does not work anymore. The variable that selects the record always has to be on the last object, because ->name has to be a method of the class passed to ->getId($id) and already has to know it's selecting record $id.

Comment: Please post the actual method from `getId($id)` and the definition of the object's class that it passes if any.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, and the help. I ended up using the solution provided below by Vaidas.